# Unable to constrain HPS peripheral pins on intel agilex fpga dev kit

Tags: intel-fpga, constraints

I'm having trouble getting the Hard Processor System (HPS, the embedded hard processor of the agilex fpga series) to work properly on the Intel Agilex Dev kit version 3. The issue says that that there is no connection between the peripheral pins I'm trying to connect and the HPS. I can't use other pins as the fpga is directly soldered to the board by Intel.

I've searched the web and the only (at least somewhat) relevant soloution I've found was to comment out the offending constraints. After doing so the fitting step succeeds. Unfortunately this solution isn't applicable as Quartus is choosing the wrong pins by default.

According to the documentation (see https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/support/boards-kits/agilex/f-fpga/agilex-f-fpga-dk-3v-es.pdf at sheet 27) the Pins I'm trying to use are the correct ones. Furthermore the golden reference design uses the exactly same constrains. Unfortunately Intel does not provide a working example on how to use the HPS on the agilex platform.

This is the exact error message im getting:

```
Error(14566): The Fitter cannot place 1 periphery component(s) due to conflicts with existing constraints (1 pin(s)). Fix the errors described in the submessages, and then rerun the Fitter. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database may also contain articles with information on how to resolve this periphery placement failure. Review the errors and then visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number. 
    Error(175020): The Fitter cannot place logic pin in region (280, 209) to (280, 209), to which it is constrained, because there are no valid locations in the region for logic of this type. 
        Info(14596): Information about the failing component(s): 
            Info(175028): The pin name(s): sd_cmd 
        Error(16234): No legal location could be found out of 1 considered location(s).  Reasons why each location could not be used are summarized below: 
            Info(175015): The I/O pad sd_cmd is constrained to the location PIN_V3 due to: User Location Constraints (PIN_V3) 
                Info(14709): The constrained I/O pad is contained within this pin 
            Error(175006): There is no routing connectivity between the pin and destination HPS_HPS 
                Info(175027): Destination: HPS_HPS hps|hps|intel_agilex_hps_0|fpga_interfaces|hps_inst|s2f_module 
                Error(175022): The pin could not be placed in any location to satisfy its connectivity requirements 
                Info(175021): The HPS_HPS was placed in location HPSHPS_X280_Y211_N1 
                Info(175029): 1 location affected 
                    Info(175029): V3
```

Note that when I'm commenting out the constrains for the sd_cmd pin I'm getting the same error - just for the next hps peripheral pin.

These are my relevant constrains:

```
set_location_assignment PIN_AC4 -to enet_gtx_clk
set_location_assignment PIN_AA4 -to enet_rx_clk
set_location_assignment PIN_AD5 -to enet_txd[0]
set_location_assignment PIN_P1 -to enet_txd[1]
set_location_assignment PIN_AF9 -to enet_txd[2]
set_location_assignment PIN_W2 -to enet_txd[3]
set_location_assignment PIN_AF7 -to enet_rxd[0]
set_location_assignment PIN_M1 -to enet_rxd[1]
set_location_assignment PIN_AB5 -to enet_rxd[2]
set_location_assignment PIN_U2 -to enet_rxd[3]
set_location_assignment PIN_V1 -to enet_tx_en
set_location_assignment PIN_T1 -to enet_rx_dv
set_location_assignment PIN_AC6 -to enet_intn
set_location_assignment PIN_AD13 -to enet_mdio
set_location_assignment PIN_F3 -to enet_mdc
set_location_assignment PIN_AA6 -to uart_tx
set_location_assignment PIN_F1 -to uart_rx
set_location_assignment PIN_H1 -to uart_rts
set_location_assignment PIN_AB7 -to hps_i2c_sda
set_location_assignment PIN_L2 -to hps_i2c_scl
set_location_assignment PIN_AC8 -to mictor_jtag_tck
set_location_assignment PIN_J2 -to mictor_jtag_tms
set_location_assignment PIN_AA8 -to mictor_jtag_tdo
set_location_assignment PIN_G2 -to mictor_jtag_tdi


set_location_assignment PIN_V3 -to sd_cmd
set_location_assignment PIN_AB9 -to sd_clk
set_location_assignment PIN_T3 -to sd_data[1]
set_location_assignment PIN_AD9 -to sd_data[0]
set_location_assignment PIN_AC10 -to sd_data[2]
set_location_assignment PIN_P3 -to sd_data[3]
set_location_assignment PIN_AA2 -to rsv_sd_resetn

#
# Set IO standarts
#

set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to uart_tx -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to uart_rx -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_intn -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_gtx_clk -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 4MA -to enet_gtx_clk -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_rx_clk -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to enet_rx_clk -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_txd[0] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to enet_txd[0] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_txd[1] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to enet_txd[1] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_txd[2] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to enet_txd[2] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_txd[3] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to enet_txd[3] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_rxd[0] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to enet_rxd[0] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_rxd[1] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to enet_rxd[1] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_rxd[2] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to enet_rxd[2] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_rxd[3] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to enet_rxd[3] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_tx_en -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to enet_tx_en -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_rx_dv -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to enet_rx_dv -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_mdio -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to enet_mdc -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 4MA -to enet_mdio -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 4MA -to enet_mdc -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name AUTO_OPEN_DRAIN_PINS ON -to enet_mdio -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to enet_mdio -entity top

# HPS sd card interface
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to sd_cmd -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to sd_cmd -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to sd_cmd -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to sd_clk -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to sd_clk -entity top
#set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to sd_clk -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to sd_data[0] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to sd_data[0] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to sd_data[0] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to sd_data[1] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to sd_data[1] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to sd_data[1] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to sd_data[2] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to sd_data[2] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to sd_data[2] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to sd_data[3] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name CURRENT_STRENGTH_NEW 8MA -to sd_data[3] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name WEAK_PULL_UP_RESISTOR ON -to sd_data[3] -entity top
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD "1.8 V" -to rsv_sd_resetn -entity top
```

I'm hoping someone with more experience on Intel FPGAs can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and like to share the solution in case someone else might end up having this issue.

I rely on custom pin layouts for the HPS periphery in the IP settings in order to constrain the correct pins for the dev kit. If one does so one cannot rely on the automatic timing estimations. If one disables the automatic timing deduction for the HPS periphery bridge and instead write one by hand the error goes away and everything works fine.